# Mapping two entities with one

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a `Contribution` entity

```
@Entity
public class ContributionEntity {

    private MovieEntity movie;

    private UserEntity user;
}
```

Both `UserEntity` and `MovieEntity` have lists

```
private Set<ContributionEntity> contributions;
```

I am looking for a way to properly map a list so that when adding a contribution, `UserEntity` and `MovieEntity` had this contribution on the list. I did

//ContributionEntity

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id")
private MovieEntity movie;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserEntity user;
```

//MovieEntity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "movie", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ContributionEntity> contributions = new ArrayList<>();
```

//UserEntity

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<ContributionEntity> contributions = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, there is a problem in this way, because I can not add a contribution to the list in `UserEntity` and `MovieEntity`, because I will add the same object twice to the database.

What mapping is correct in this situation?

Comment: I don't get the context. In which class does the code in the last code section belong?

Comment: It's not directly related, but wouldn't be better to create Contributions with provided data instead of adding it twice to lists in User and Movie? I mean I think that Contribution shouldn't exists without user or movie, but that can happen in your way.

Comment: @Matt: I edited the question.

Comment: you can drop the `one-to-many` side of the relationship and treat movie and user as Meta entities. By doing so only `many-to-one` relation will exist and you can fetch the contribution list for movies by something like 'findAllByMovie(Movie movie)' (depends on your persistent layer choice)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, adding the `Contribution` to both lists would not work, as Hibernate doesn't know it's the same object. So, either you could, which is quite cumbersome, create a `Contribution`, set the respective `Movie` and add it to the `User`'s contributions. Or the other way round, add a `User` to the newly created `Contribution` and add it to the `Movie`'s contribution list. Mind that you would have to make sure the `Contribution` is persisted, too (e.g. by `@Cascade` or manually saving it).

A better approach would be to set the focus on the `Contribution`. If you create and save a `Contribution` it will be automatically present in both lists (not in the current transaction, though, but that's probably not required anyway).